# Ответы - комментарии

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии, тревоги, ответы, не-является-ответом

Мы все привыкли, что если в ответе мало текста, то это скорее комментарий. Но замечал, что большинство ответов, в которых есть ответ, помечают, как комментарий.

К примеру, встретил недавно такой ответ:

> Почему Вы не открываете сразу splash screen при запуске приложения,
>   которая (по завершению таймера...) откроет главную форму?

<sup>Вопрос: "[Как создать splash screen в visual c++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635511/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-splash-screen-%D0%B2-visual-c)"</sup>

Его пометили, как комментарий. Но я не считаю, что это комментарий, ведь в нём содержится ответ на вопрос.

**Так вот вопрос:** если ответ содержит ответ на вопрос, но не имеет вид полноценного ответа, то нужно ли отмечать его, как комментарий или лучше посоветовать автору ответа дополнить ответ?

*Простите за тавтологию.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если ответ чрезмерно краток, но решает поставленную задачу, то он, безусловно должен быть ответом, а не комментарием. При этом, односложные фразы ответы, оформленные тем более в виде наводящих вопросов, довольно сложно считать полноценным ответом и такие сообщения рекомендуется довести до более полноценного содержимого. Некоторые участники добавляют к таким сообщениям комментарии вида:

> Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы ...

где вместо троеточия указывается дополнительная информация, которая по мнению комментатора поможет сделать ответ полноценным.

Comment: Ну в примере, в вопросе содержится ответ. Нужно открывать сразу splash screen при запуске приложения.. :)