# Ценность односложных и/или коротких ответов

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, тревоги, ответы, удаление-ответов

### **Синопсис**

Будучи зарегистрированным на EnSO и, с недавних пор, на RuSO, я начал замечать неоднозначные вещи, связанные с ответами на вопросы.

*Сразу оговорюсь, что читал справку о том, как задавать вопросы и отвечать на них на англоязычной и на русскоязычной версиях сайта.*

### **Действия**

Множество раз мне попадались односложные ответы, которые, собственно, не несли никакой информации. Я полагал, что модераторы в состоянии отслеживать подобные вещи и оперативно их устранять, поэтому *лично* не предпринимал никаких действий.

Однако совсем недавно наткнулся на подобную ситуацию здесь, на RuSO - [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878787/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-http-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83).
Я не знаком с данным пользователем и это ни в коем случае не преследование, но на мой взгляд, подобный ответ не совсем коррелирует с ценностями SE в целом. Попытавшись поставить себя на место человека, находящегося в поиске решения данной проблемы я пришел к выводу, что решение является слишком явным и напрашивающимся для проверки в первую очередь.

Поэтому я решил действовать - для начала оставил комментарий, чтобы автор сам мог предпринять некоторые меры (например, расширить свой ответ дополнительными рекомендациями). А впоследствии, когда никакого ответа от автора не получил (имею в виду ответа на свой комментарий), я пометил вопрос, как требующий внимания модератора и подробно изложил свою точку зрения.

Тем не менее, модератор отклонил мою тревогу, указав, что

> На мой взгляд ответ вполне имеет ценность)

При всем уважении к автору вопроса (вопрос написан, следует отметить, весьма толково, такое редко встретишь) и модератору (которому приходится реагировать на все эти "тревоги") я все-таки считаю, что такого рода ответы (не на "тревогу" - на вопрос) недопустимы.

### **Что мы имеем?**

[Такой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/837229/delphi-10-2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-microsoftword) - ответ на вопрос дан самим автором, но ответ совсем не понятен. Почему именно так, а не иначе? Человек, который придет на сайт с похожей заминкой скопирует код из ответа, код заработает/не заработает и человек задаст новый вопрос вида "Помогите с кодом!", получит минусов, вопрос закроют и т.д.

### **В сухом остатке**

С точки зрения "ответчика" следует приложить максимум усилий чтобы дать наиболее полный ответ. В конце концов, это же интересно и полезно не только для попросившего помощи, но также и для самого помогающего. В конце концов, RuSO равно как и EnSO не являются `FAQ` в узком смысле этой аббревиатуры.

**Ключевая мысль всей этой "стены" текста:

*нужно ли ставить "тревогу" на ответы, которые слишком коротки (смотрите пример выше), или пустить все на самотек (может, кто-нибудь другой похлопочет за меня)?***

Спасибо, что прочитали все это.

Comment: Прекрасный вопрос, который фактически подробнее ковыряет "ответы на грани" - я буквально на днях [спрашивал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7829/213987) подобное на мете.

Comment: Действительно, видел его сегодня, однако, ответа там так и не было. Может тут хоть что-нибудь подскажут. Лично я придерживаюсь удаления, либо уведомления автора о том, что его вопрос *будет удален*, если вопрос не будет "отформатирован" надлежащим образом. Надлежащим - согласно правилам и т.п.

Comment: Ответ там был, однако из-за того что я не смог хорошо сформулировать примеры пограничных сообщений (а я честно перерыл свои тревоги в глубину на месяц) тот вопрос свёлся к совсем пустым ответам типа "всем спасибо, я разобралась" и все ответы там достаточно чёткие: удалять. А у вас вопрос касается немного других кейсов - поэтому вопросы не дубликаты и нужно рассматривать отдельно и у нас уже есть как минимум одно мнение (модератора) "не удалять", которое отличается от рекомендаций моего вопроса.

Comment: Для меня вопрос также актуален, потому что у разных участников стандарты краткости ответа разные. Как раз один из ваших примеров - [мой вчерашний из очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/879533/213987) и у этого отвечающего представление "надо дать однострочный ответ без наливания воды" (я приводил в пример [похожий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/824405/213987) просто чуть подробнее).

Comment: @AK, если проблема глобальна (модераторам виднее, я встречаю 3-5 вопросов в неделю), то следует сразу же удалять такие ответы, а их авторов (если есть возможность) информировать, почему это произошло. Информирование необходимо для того, чтоб автор ответа мог перефразировать свой вопрос. Или делать так, как сейчас делается при закрытии вопроса: плашечка желтая под текстом вопроса, в которой указаны причины закрытия и лица, инициировавшие это закрытие.

Comment: Либо можно информировать автора по поводу того, что его вопрос/ответ будет удален в связи с (*ссылка на правила*). И, скажем, по истечении суток (срок можно будет выбрать), удалять вопрос/ответ либо в ручном, либо (хорошо бы) в автоматическом режиме. Вероятно, это утопическая идея и лично я не представляю, как ее реализовать, но это лучше, чем встречать "шумные" вопросы/ответы.

Comment: Вы в одном вопросе смешали проблемы с вопросами (автор попросил ссылку, и сам дал ссылку), проблемы с ответами (короткие, простые и решающие проблему вопросы - это хорошо!), вопросы/ответы, которые лично вам не вполне понятны, вопросы, которые вам показались вопросами "сделайте за меня" (на самом деле приведенный вами пример - это обычный вопрос). какого ответа или каких действий модераторов вы ожидаете?

Comment: @Dima может стоит как-то отредактировать вопрос, чтобы выделить ключевую мысль? В текущем виде темы поднимаются важные, но по итогу получается винегрет из разных (хотя и связанных) тем.

Comment: Второму ответу (про "карусели") кинул минус и тревогу, за наводку спасибо. Остальные вроде нормальные. Мы не удаляем ответы тревогами, просто потому что они короткие или неполные. Вы можете минусануть, если не нравятся.

Comment: @PashaPash, я добавил ответ в тело вопроса, поскольку комментарии весьма ограничены и малочитабельны.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, дело не в "нравятся они мне или нет". Дело в необходимости помечать их и привлекать внимание модератора, поскольку по-моему мнению (с опорой на правила) они не соответствуют последним.

Comment: " в которых нет и намека на усилия решения проблемы" - какого намека вы ожидали? кучу нерабочего кода? нагугленную копипасту?

Comment: К сожалению, ваш вопрос слишком общий. Многие из тем, которые вы упомянули, уже неоднократно обсуждались. Включая простые вопросы (и простые ответы!), вопросы без кода, вопросы "сделайте за меня", вопросы. Пожалуйста, придерживайтесь принципа "один вопрос - одна проблема" - он действует и на мете тоже, а не только на основном сайте.

Comment: @PashaPash, нет, но описания: что делал, какие инструменты применял. И да, куча нерабочего кода тоже может помочь. Зачастую благодаря "куче" видно человека, которого не следует отсылать к фрилансерам.

Comment: @Dima а зачем вам описание что делал и какие инструменты применял? это поможет дать ответ, при условии, что это "делал" и "применял" не никак не сработало? По поводу посыла на фриланс - отправлять на фриланс можно только тех, кто по ошибке решил, что SO - это сайт для поиска исполнителей - т.е. тех, кто явно в вопросе упоминает нежелание делать самому, и предлагает вознаграждение. Во всех остальных случаях - посыл на фриланс - это грубое нарушение Code of Conduct.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83010/discussion-on-question-by-dima-------).

Comment: @Dima Ну тогда вы неверно её используете. Она для нетривиальных ситуаций и модератор не имеет права удалять пост просто потому что он "не очень полезен", надеюсь вы меня понимаете. Модератор будет злоупотреблять своими полномочиями если удалит ответ, который содержит хотя бы намёк на решение проблемы. Я думаю, что вам будет полезен [этот пост на главной мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/346987) про вашу проблему. Представьте будто вы использовали тревогу "не является ответом" — суть бы не поменялась.

Answer (score 5):

Вопрос слишком много тем одновременно затрагивает:

1. Качество вопросов.
2. Качество ответов.
3. Ответы-ссылки.
4. Ответы, которые не несут пользы сообществу.
5. Оценка важности вопроса/ответа для сообщества.

Хорошо бы под каждую тему свой вопрос задавать на мете, чтоб более предметно можно было обсуждать.

---

> Однако совсем недавно наткнулся на подобный вопрос здесь, на RuSO -
>   этот вопрос. Я не знаком с данным пользователем и это ни в коем случае
>   не преследование, но на мой взгляд, подобный ответ не совсем
>   коррелирует с ценностями SE в целом. Попытавшись поставить себя на
>   место человека, находящегося в поиске решения данной проблемы я пришел
>   к выводу, что решение является **слишком явным** и напрашивающимся для
>   проверки в первую очередь.

Я сам часто становлюсь заложником вот таких мыслей. Поверьте, многие программисты про администрирование, открытые порты, фаервол и вот это всё ничего не знаю. Поэтому, для таких людей ответ "**нужно было настроить разрешённые исходящие порты**" вполне себя полезный.

> Вот, например, еще один вопрос. Автор сам на него ответил, причем не
>   слишком удачно - просто привел ссылку на сторонний сайт (который через
>   месяц-другой "ляжет" и решения проблемы для данного вопроса уже не
>   будет, ибо автор ответа не удосужился даже скопировать хоть что-нибудь
>   мало-мальски значимое с сайта, на который он дал ссылку).

Тут, собственно, не важно, кто дал ответ. Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются. Для таких ответов специальная причина удаления в очереди есть.

> Здесь снова те же грабли - ответ на вопрос дан самим автором, но ответ
>   совсем не понятен. Почему именно так, а не иначе? Человек, который
>   придет на сайт с похожей заминкой скопирует код из ответа, код
>   заработает/не заработает и человек задаст новый вопрос вида "Помогите
>   с кодом!", получит минусов, вопрос закроют и т.д.

Формально тут всё хорошо. Есть вопрос, есть ответ, который решает проблему. Полезно ли это для сообщества и для будущих участников? Вряд ли. Удалять только из-за этого? Если автор захочет - вперёд. Но по формальным признакам нету причин удалять такой вопрос/ответ.

> И напоследок такой вопрос. Выглядит как призыв "сделайте за меня", не
>   так ли? Хорошо,что хоть автор вопроса свое решение дал в своем же
>   ответе (а ведь мог бы просто написать "Все, разобрался сам.").

Если бы я такой вопрос увидел в очереди на проверку, то, скорей всего, закрыл бы с причиной "домашка". Если бы автор привёл пример, как это сделать на x86, то было бы куда лучше. А с ответом проблем вообще не вижу.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4886/213987